# C++ std::regex litteral pipe error_escape exception

Tags: c++, regex

I am having trouble with a small regular expression which matches a single pipe character. I am always getting a regex_error exception with the error_escape code.

In it's most basic form, the escape on the pipe does not work in posix, extended posix or default syntax modes

```
std::regex("\\|", std::regex_constants::extended);
```

I have tried all 3 modes with 2 backslashes, just one and none.

I even tried to match using the escape for the actual value of the pipe character:

```
\\0x7c or \0x7c
```

With the same result.

What am i doing wrong? All The other regular expressions in my code work, including several similar literal character escapes (+, *, etc).

(Please do not suggest boost)

Comment: What leads you to believe it doesn't work? Or more accurately, what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0b6198080ecdcc5

Comment: Sorry about that, I somehow forgot to add that! I've updated the description with the exception I am receiving

Comment: well, my attempt to reproduce the problem failed to do so (see link in previous comment). What compiler/standard library are you using? And which versions?

Comment: g++ in c++11 mode... Version 4.8.1

Comment: minGW. I'm in a windows environment

Comment: I don't believe that std::regex is fully supported by g++ v4.8.1, but it's a library issue and I have no idea how that would work out in a minGW environment. I'm pretty sure the answer is going to be "upgrade". I'll dig out minimum version numbers in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earliest version of GNU libstdc++ which supports `std::regex` is v4.9.0, so if you are using libstdc++ v4.8, you are going to find lots of errors in the regex implementation. It's unfortunate that it was released with a partial and generally unusable implementation, but that's water under the bridge now.

(For the record, here's the [implementation status](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011) from the v4.8.3 documentation. Although that document *says* "This page describes the C++ support in mainline GCC SVN, not in any particular release", it is, afaik, an actual record of what was available at that moment in time; however, the only hint is in the URL itself. The [release notes for v4.9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html) list `std::regex` as being newly added.)

I'm sorry to say that I do not use MinGW, nor do I ever intend to, so I am not qualified to say whether there is a plausible workaround. Apparently, `std::regex` works fine in the Windows C++ standard library implementation (something else which I never use). And, of course, there is always boost but that seems to be out of scope for this question :)

Comment: Shame, that's the latest version minGW has available.

Comment: I'm working in a linux environment for now, but I will need windows platform compatibility, thus minGW

Comment: @rscarson: According to the comments here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823969/regex-error-escape-while-parsing-escape-characters-using-mingw -- you can use a 64-bit mingw and thereby have v5.2